# TP4056 Lithium-ion Charger Module with USB-C PD

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, usb-c, tp4056, usb-pd

I have a USB-C version of one of [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32930640893.html) TP4056 Lithium-ion charger modules. It works well so far from limited testing (the battery I've used has its own protection), but there's a lot more to test.

[image: TP4056 Lithium-ion Charger Module]

The problem I'm having is that it works perfectly with a "USB-A male to USB-C male", but it doesn't work with a "USB-C male to USB-C male" cable.  It also doesn't work with a "laptop USB-C charger" which does do 5 V.

I presume it's to do with the voltage negotiation of USB-C Power Distribution, but I can't find anything online (except one review on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MDPLQ18) saying the same) about this specific case, though I'm sure many people have experienced it.

Does anyone know a safe way to configure this to automatically provide 5 V PD? I suspect the charger isn't providing anything until a device correctly requests/draws a voltage. Putting a voltmeter across the input +/- pads, it briefly goes to 300 mV, but quickly drops.  With a working cable/charger, it gives 4.98 V  constant. Perhaps bridging a couple of the USB-C pins on the module is needed?

**Edit1**

The closest schematic I can see is from [link](https://www.sunrom.com/p/lithum-battery-charger-with-protection-microusb), which shows it for a Micro USB, but it appears in all intents and purposes to be the same (it's a generic module)
[image: TP4056 Lithium-ion Charger Module Schematic]

The charger is one of [these](https://fonehaus.co.uk/products/official-google-tc-g1000-uk-18w-usb-type-c-3-pin-charger) "*GOOGLE MAINS WALL CHARGER TC G1000-UK + 3.1 Type C REVERSIBLE CONNECTOR DATA CABLE WHITE*"

- Input: 100-240 V 50-60 Hz 0.5 A
- Output: 5.0 V - 3.0 A / 9 V ~2.0 A 3.1,

Information from [here](https://gtrusted.com/pixel-2-18w-usb-c-power-adapter) states that it supports "the common USB Power Delivery profiles of 15 watts (5 volts @ 3 amps) and 18 watts (9 volts @ 2 amps)", but not much else could be found.

Comment: Please provide schematics and any other engineering documentation you have for it. Without that we can't help from just a picture of the board.

Comment: Null - Thanks for the feedback, I have updated accordingly.

Thanks @SamGibson for the edits to format it correctly.  Sorry I hadn't done that initially.

Comment: Does it not work regardless of the 4 orientations of the usb c cable?

Comment: 4 orientations ... Damn. Sorry, I tried three, I should have tried the fourth.

Comment: @Aubs have you found a module like this that works for usb-c to usb-c or did you ever try modifying it like the accepted answer with success?

Comment: @keyneom - No, sorry, I didn't look any further.  I've not gotten round to testing the solution, but I probably will do at some point in the near future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the schematic is complete, the board is missing the two 5.1kΩ pull-down resistors on the CC1 and CC2 lines of the USB C connector. This charger board has the sink role. So the relevant resistors are *Rd* in the below figure.

Since these two lines do not existing on a USB A connector, power supplies built for USB A don't care. However chargers and computers with USB C ports and in particular support for USB-PD require proper CC1/CC2 resistors.

[image: Pull-up/pull-down CC model]

*See figure 4-5 in [USB Type-C Spec R2.0](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf)*

The USB-C 12 pin connector probably has the same layout as this one (a Molex USB connector, see https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/2171790001_sd.pdf):

[image: Molex USB connector pins]

CC1 is on pin A5, CC2 is on pin B5. So with good soldering skills, you can add the 5.1kΩ resistors between those pins and ground.

Comment: Thank you Codo for the very helpful information, it sounds pretty plausible. I'm fully injected with vodka tonight (04:35GMT+1), so I'll probably have a try in the morning or on Sunday. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Thanks again Codo, I've not been able to solder the required pins, they're quite confined and I don't have the expertise yet (I haven't attempted, but will at some point in the future).  Using your information as a guide and a bit more research, I've confirmed this is the correct answer, so have marked it as such. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Having one of those board also from aliexpress, I can confirm this is indeed their problem when testing it with an USB C breakout. There aren't even tracks on the PCB for the CC lines, so you need to solder to the tiny pins of the connector

Comment: Doesn’t R4 on the blue PCB in the OP question provide the “selection” of the 5v input to the charger? I mean if you solder a 5.1k 0201 SMD resistor won’t it “tell” the charger to provide 5v?